# How to repeat a console.writeline x times in c#?

Tags: c#, repeat, console.writeline

I'm trying to repeat a console.writeline x times (in C#).

The x (type long) is a user input from a console.writeline. So if x is 2, I want 2 console.writelines to follow it. 
I tried fixing it with Enumerable.Repeat, but that did not work. Also a while loop in which I subtract 1 from x until it is 0 didn't do the trick. 
Suggestions?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just use a `for` loop? `for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { Console.WriteLine(...); }`?

Comment: for loop, maybe??

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Any proof **while** didn't work? Maybe your condition is wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406741/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-repeat-an-action/44730742) which has some neat solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach without loops as stated in other comments. Mark as answer if that's fit your needs. Note it has to be int.

```
class Program
{
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
           string input = Console.ReadLine();
           int d;
           if (int.TryParse(input, out d))
           Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Whatever",d)));
           Console.ReadLine();
      }
}
```

Comment: Why someone put -1?

Comment: @Amber try my solution, its just has to be int over long without any loop.

Comment: Thanks! That saves me some for loops!

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    long loopCounter = 0;
    long.TryParse(input, out loopCounter);

    for (int i = 0; i < loopCounter; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My Message");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I didn't use the for loop, because it would have the same effect as the while loop. Because for each writeline I also need a readline to read it in and than the spaces are really big.

Comment: @Amber Which effect? It's really unclear what your problem exactly is...

Comment: @Amber So is this answer correct? If so please mark it.